# Win API - how to start desktop programs?

Tags: c#, .net

In the pictire below is my desktop (win7 pro). I want in C# code to start the icon Broadband.lnk
[image]

And when i start it to push the button Disconnect shown on this picture [image]

I tried with using System.Diagnostics; but cmd doesnt work... Any ideas how to start the desktop icon and after this to attach to its window and call the button?

I tried with cmd this code and it didnt worked:

```
        Process cmd = new Process();

        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput =
        true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput =
        true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        cmd.Start();

        /* execute "dir" */

        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(@".\Desktop\Broadband.lnk");
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
```

Comment: Don't you think that a better question would be: How to programmatically disconnect Broadband connection? Your approach to your problem is rather unusual.

Comment: Can you post your code using `System.Diagnostics` to execute the shortcut? I've done this before and it worked. Not necessarily with an Internet connection shortcut, but with other shortcuts. You didn't mention *how* it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use `netsh` as detailed in Microsoft KB: [Disconnect from a network in Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732379.aspx) if you want to do this in script, otherwise look at the Win32 APIs on which `netsh` is built. And never, ever, **ever** press buttons on the screen programmatically. People were *burned at the stake* for less.

Answer (score 1):

May be process.start can help you: http://dotnetperls.com/process-start